# Could not load assembly <asm_name> exception has been thrown by target of an invocation

Tags: c#, .net

In my application, there is a module which is dynamically loads dll and gives the result set. "Could not load assembly  exception has been thrown by target of an invocation" exception is thrown when it tries to load a particular dll for a particular operation frequently. At the same time, if I do different operation with that dll the operation gets successful.

If anyone of you faced this type issue kindly share your suggestions.

Comment: What's the `InnerException`?

Comment: Hi Chris,

Object reference not set to an instance.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: Exception: Unable to load assembly <asm_name>, Version=4.7.0.1038, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Inner Exception: Unable to load assembly <asm_name>, Version=4.7.0.1038, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I don't have stack trace for this error.

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` doesn't really say much without some context, so we'll still need the stack trace to be able to help you.

Comment: I found that issue. There was an object accessed with null reference and I fixed that one. Thank u for your support